# c# MVC 5 User Store custom findby

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.6

the default provided FindByIdAsync, FindById etc work as expected.

How would I go about implementing a FindBySomeOtherField?

at a minimum i'd like to be able to UserManager.FindBy any field off the main AspNetUsers table.  Such as UserManager.FindByPhoneNumber

Ideally, i'd be able to UserManager.FindByCustomField

I do NOT want to implement a completely new user store.

I guess worst case scenario I could go find and copy the entire user store for MVC 5 as is and add it to my project and then implement it, however, i'd rather just add a class that includes the function and be done since I rather like the user store as is and just want to extend it's functionality.

Comment: Does it **need** to go into the `UserManager`?  You can query the tables directly via Entity Framework.  Under the good, this is what the `UserManager` ultimately does.

Comment: add Entity Framework to your project and then use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Aye, that solution would work, I would prefer something more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but the following should work?

```
IEnumerable<[Object]> results = [ObjectCollection].Where(u => u.[Field] == [Value])
```

OR

```
[Object] result = [ObjectCollection].SingleOrDefault(u => u.[Field] == [Value])
```

If you want it for a specific field, you could extract it into a method;

```
public [Object] FindBy[Field]([FieldType] value)
{
    return [ObjectCollection].SingleOrDefault(u => u.[Field] == [Value])
}
```